# C++ convert float to hex using only whole number math

Tags: c++, floating-point, int, type-conversion

I need to convert a whole number that should be considered a float into its hexadecimal equivalent.

For example:

> Float To Hex
>
> 1     = 0x3f800000
>
> 2     = 0x40000000
>
> 12345 = 0x4640e400

It will always be whole numbers, never fractions such as 0.5.
This could be done with memory assignment or a formatting function, but the situation its being used it, it has no memory access and no API calls at all.

I tried this idea, but it doesn't work at all
http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/219928-how-convert-float-hex#post886069

Comment: I'm not seeing how `1` could ever equal `0x3f800000` sorry.

Comment: Best I can tell you want to reinterpret a 32-bit IEEE-754 single-precision float as an unsigned integer, then print that as a hex number. If so, you could try this: `unsigned int floatAsUint (float a) { unsigned int i; memcpy (&i, &a, sizeof(i)); return i; } printf ("%g %08x\n", 1.0f, floatAsUint(1.0f));`. This has "memory access", but I don't see how you can process any data without "memory access". Please clarify.

Comment: If the use of `memcpy()` is problematic because it is an "API call", you could use this instead: `unsigned int floatAsUint (float a) { unsigned int i; unsigned char *ap = (unsigned char *)&a, *ip = (unsigned char *)&i; for (unsigned int c = 0; c < sizeof (i); c++) { *ip++ = *ap++; } return i; }`

Comment: But why don't you like `union` solution? For me it's more elegant.

Comment: @JonathanPotter if you look at 1.0f in ram, it is 0x3F800000

Comment: @njuffa that is memory access, pointers. It must be math based.

Answer (score 1):

Function `floatAsUint_s()` below re-interprets a 32-bit IEEE-754 `float` as an `unsigned int` for any input x for which |x| is in [1, 2<sup>128</sup>), or zero. The information is extracted from the `float` one bit at a time and the resulting `unsigned int` is built from those bits one bit at at time. Provided both the input and output reside in processor registers rather than memory, no additional memory is required during the re-interpretation process.

```
/* re-interpret IEEE-754 float x, |x| in [1, 2**128) or 0, as unsigned int */
unsigned int floatAsUint_s (float x)
{
    unsigned int i;

    /* extract sign bit, proceed with absolute value */
    i = (((x == 0.0f) ? (1.0f / x) : x) < 0.0f) ? 0x80000000 : 0x00000000;
    x = (((x == 0.0f) ? (1.0f / x) : x) < 0.0f) ? -x : x;
    /* extract exponent, which is positive per specification */
    if (x >= 1.84467441e19f) { x /= 1.84467441e19f; i |= 1 << 29; }
    if (x >= 4.29496730e9f)  { x /= 4.29496730e9f;  i |= 1 << 28; }
    if (x >= 65536.0f)       { x /= 65536.0f;       i |= 1 << 27; }
    if (x >= 256.0f)         { x /= 256.0f;         i |= 1 << 26; }
    if (x >= 16.0f)          { x /= 16.0f;          i |= 1 << 25; }
    if (x >= 4.0f)           { x /= 4.0f;           i |= 1 << 24; }
    if (x >= 2.0f)           { x /= 2.0f;           i |= 1 << 23; }
    i += (x == 0.0f) ? 0 : (127 << 23); // add IEEE-754 specified exponent bias
    /* extract mantissa */
    x = x - 1.0f; // remove hidden bit
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 << 22; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 << 21; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 << 20; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 << 19; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 << 18; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 << 17; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 << 16; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 << 15; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 << 14; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 << 13; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 << 12; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 << 11; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 << 10; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 <<  9; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 <<  8; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 <<  7; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 <<  6; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 <<  5; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 <<  4; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 <<  3; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 <<  2; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 <<  1; } 
    x = x + x; if (x >= 1.0f) { x -= 1.0f; i |= 1 <<  0; } 
    return i;
}

/* reference implementation */
unsigned int floatAsUint (float a)
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned char *ap = (unsigned char *)&a, *ip = (unsigned char*)&i;
    for (unsigned int c = 0; c < sizeof (i); c++) { 
        *ip++ = *ap++;
    }
    return i;
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{                          
    unsigned int res, ref;
    float s = -1.0f;
    while (s < 2.0f) {
        float x = 0.0f;
        while (x < 3.40282346e38f) {
            ref = floatAsUint (s * x);
            res = floatAsUint_s (s * x);
            if (ref != res) {
                printf ("error @ % 15.8e: res= %08x ref=%08x\n", x, res, ref);
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            x = (x == 0.0f) ? 1.0f : nextafterf (x, 3.40282346e38f);
        }
        s += 2.0f;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

An alternative interpretation of the specification in the question is as follows: Given an `int` x, |x| in [0, 2<sup>24</sup>], produce the IEEE-754 single-precision encoding of the value of x, stored in a `uint32_t`. Use only integer operations for the transformation.

The bit pattern of a positive non-zero integer <= 2<sup>24</sup> is identical to the bit pattern of the mantissa (with hidden bit restored) of the IEEE-754 `float` it is converted to, only appropriately shifted. We therefore need to normalize by left shifting the integer until its most significant 1-bit is in the position of the hidden mantissa bit, which is bit 23. The number of shifts needed to normalize tells us the magnitude of the integer in powers of two, and thus determines the exponent of the floating-point number. We need to remember to add the exponent bias prescribed by IEEE-754, then combine the sign, exponent, and mantissa portions for the final result.

The function `make_float_s()` in the code below implements the algorithm described above.

```
#include <stdint.h>

/* For |a| in [0,2**24], generate IEEE-754 float encoding with same value */
uint32_t make_float_s (int a)
{
    uint32_t i;
    int e = 0;

    i = (a < 0) ? 0x80000000 : 0x00000000;   // sign bit
    if (a) {
        a = (a < 0) ? -a : a;
        while (a < 0x00800000) {   // normalize mantissa
            e++;
            a = a + a;
        }
        e = 127 + (22 - e); // determine biased exponent
        i += (e << 23) + a; // combine sign, exponent, mantissa
    }
    return i;
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

uint32_t float_as_uint (float a)
{
    uint32_t i;
    memcpy (&i, &a, sizeof(i));
    return i;
}

/* reference function */
uint32_t make_float (int a)
{
    return float_as_uint ((float)a);
}

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t res, ref;
    int a, s;

    a=1; printf("%d encoded as IEEE-754 float: %08x\n", a, make_float_s(a));
    a=2; printf("%d encoded as IEEE-754 float: %08x\n", a, make_float_s(a));
    a=12345; printf("%d encoded as IEEE-754 float: %08x\n", a, make_float_s(a));

    s = -1;
    while (s < 2) {
        a = 0;
        while (a <= 16777216) {
            res = make_float_s (s * a);
            ref = make_float (s * a);
            if (res != ref) {
                printf ("error @ % 7d: res=%08x  ref=%08x\n", s * a, res, ref);
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            a++;
        }
        s += 2;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: but the OP is specifying "using only whole number math" and you're using floating-point math

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Based on the test vectors given, OP wants to *re-interprete*, rather than convert the data as the title claims. Two proposals were made to access the data in question directly as integer (either via union, or copy operation) but OP disqualified both under the "no memory" provision. So the data must be read as floating-point. Once the data is in a floating-point variable, we can't operate on it with integer operations, but must use operations that accept a floating-point number as input. If that is also disqualified, there is no solution, as the requirements are contradictory.

Comment: I like this idea. Never realized that we can get the raw bits using only floating-point operations. But I don't think this works with negative zero

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: The code above could be extended to include negative zero. The `signbit()` function would be the natural way to extract the sign but OP declared "APIs" off-limits. We can get the sign of zero by examining the sign of the inverse (which is +/- infinity in IEEE-754 arithmetic): `float t = (x == 0.0f) ? (1.0f / x) : x; i = (t < 0.0f) ? 0x80000000 : 0x00000000;`. The way I understood the OP's specification, no operands less than 1 need to be handled, therefore I did not add code to handle zero. I guess some people may consider zero a "whole number" so I'll add that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union` for this.
Something like:

```
union data {
    float f_data;
    char c_data[4];
};
```

And usage:

```
data d1;
d1.f_data = 12345;
```

After that `d1.c_data` contain hex values you need.

Comment: can't use structs either, it has to be math based

Comment: @John: So direct re-interpretation of the data by any means is specifically disallowed? Note that depending on your platform (which you did not specify), such re-interpretation may be able to occur in registers, without writing the `float` to memory and reading the data back as an `unsigned int`. In the mathematical approach that you request, is it allowed to introduce temporary variables, or does this also count as using "memory access"? Are you able to divulge what drives the "no memory access" requirement?

Comment: @njuffa you can use as many variables as you want, as long as they are whole number types such as int, uint, unsigned char, etc. Just no float point data types.

Comment: I am puzzled by this specification. How is the original floating-point data supposed to enter the desired re-interpretation computation if it is not held in a variable of a floating-point type? Clearly it can't be in held in a variable of integer type yet, as that is only possible *after* re-interpretation into an (unsigned) integer, which, however, is the very task we are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @John: Is your specification actually this: "Given an integer x, |x| in [0,2**23), produce the IEEE-754 single-precision encoding of the value of x, stored in a uint32_t. Use only integer operations for the transformation"?